# cannot get fix react-native-router-flux error even after uninatsalling it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using react-native `0.47.1`. I was playing around different versions of `react-native-router-flux`. Long story short, I messed things up and started to get an error while running the app. Then decided to uninstall the `router-flus` to start it from beginning. I used all ways below:

```
npm uninstall <name> removes

npm uninstall <name> --save 

npm uninstall <name> --save-dev 

npm -g uninstall <name> --save
```

and now, when I try

```
npm list react-native-router-flux
```

I get this message:

[image]

but still when running the project get the same error as shown below

[image]

[image]

EDITED:

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "manager",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^4.2.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.47.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does `react-native-router-flux` exist in your `package.json` file?

Comment: @VahidBoreiri  no, i edited the quesion with my package.json

Comment: Did you try to remove nod_modules folder and run `npm start` or `yarn` to get packages again?

Comment: @VahidBoreiri yes but didn't work